# Laravel 5.8 Unknow database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MariaDb1027Platform may not support it

Tags: enums, migration, laravel-5.8

This error ocurred in moment that execute my migration:

**Error**: Laravel 5.8 Unknow database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MariaDb1027Platform may not support it.

Migration

```
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        if (Schema::hasColumn('users', 'userType')) {
            $table->dropColumn('userType');
        }

        $table->unsignedInteger('usertype_id')->default(1);
        $table->foreign('usertype_id')->references('id')->on('usertypes');
    });

    //Table
    |id| description|
    |1 | Type 1     |
    |2 | Type 2     |
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in the migration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function __construct()
{
    DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('enum', 'string');
}
```