# Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL80Platform may not support it

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-filament, filamentphp

Tech stack: `Laravel ^10, FilamantPhP ^3.x`

When I tried to create a Filament-PHP resource for a Model `Staff` (to show in the admin panel) with the command `php artisan make:filament-resource Staff --generate` the terminal threw an error:

Unable to read table schema for model [App\Models\Staff]: An unknown database type enum requested; Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySQL80Platform may not support it.

Corresponding to this The `create_staff_table` contains gender field where enums have been used, Here is the code for `create_staff_table`,

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateStaffsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create("staffs", function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->onDelete("cascade");
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string("first_name");
            $table->string("last_name");
            $table->date("dob");
            $table->enum("gender", ["male", "female", "other"]);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("hotel_id");
            $table
                ->foreign("hotel_id")
                ->references("id")
                ->on("hotels");
            $table->unsignedBigInteger("user_id");
            $table
                ->foreign("user_id")
                ->references("id")
                ->on("users");
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists("staffs");
    }
}
```

The staff model code is below:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Staff extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "staffs";
    protected $fillable = [
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "dob",
        "gender",
        "hotel_id",
        "user_id",
    ];
    public function hotel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Hotel::class);
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

As I mentioned earlier, with command, the StaffResource.php file was created, but schema and table were empty, throwing the error described above

This is the `StaffResource.php` code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use App\Filament\Resources\StaffResource\Pages;
use App\Filament\Resources\StaffResource\RelationManagers;
use App\Models\Staff;
use Filament\Forms;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;

class StaffResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Staff::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = "heroicon-o-rectangle-stack";

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form->schema([
            //
        ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                //
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
                //
            ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            "index" => Pages\ListStaff::route("/"),
            "create" => Pages\CreateStaff::route("/create"),
            "edit" => Pages\EditStaff::route("/{record}/edit"),
        ];
    }
}
```

So using the `--generate` suffix, all forms and tables should have been added, right? but it's empty, so could anyone please guide me through it? Thanks for your time; I appreciate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.8 Unknow database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MariaDb1027Platform may not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125580/laravel-5-8-unknow-database-type-enum-requested-doctrine-dbal-platforms-mariadb)

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried that solution but it didn't work